# Quarzt: store JobDataMap before/without scheduling a job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

*Is there any way to persist `JobDataMap` without triggering/scheduling any jobs? Can I afterwards (on callback) start a `Job` with the stored `JobDataMap`?*

I have many jobs scheduled with Quartz an I pass `JobDataMap` to those jobs:

```
scheduler.triggerJob(new JobKey("job-name", "job-group"), myJobDataMap);
```

Now I need to implement job queue since there are jobs which can't be launched in parallel. The problem is that state (`JobDataMap`) for some jobs is passed from client, and should be persisted for queueing purposes. In other hand I can't schedule job on user request since I don't know when it should be executed! (It should be executed right after previous job)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can use the method [`addJob(JobDetail, boolean)`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#addJob(org.quartz.JobDetail,%20boolean)) to add a new job to the Scheduler without actually scheduling it. Quoting the docs:

> The `Job` will be 'dormant' until it is scheduled with a `Trigger`, or `Scheduler.triggerJob()` is called for it.

Your data map would be part of the `JobDetail` parameter.